# how to calculate values in c#

Tags: c#

sorry im not sure how to make a working windows form demo here,i have the following windows form application that when you click on a button it adds numbers to a sequence as follows,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //how to call the above result and display only the reminder values
           }
```

output

```
3,5,9,17,31,57,105,193,355,653,1201,2209,4063,7473
```

what i am trying to achieve is that from the above output i  want to display the numbers that has no remainders,so for example if i divide each number by 3 3/3=1 no remainder,5/3=1.66 remainder,9/3=3 no remainder. Based on the above output how do i calculate  a new label with the  output that would show  3,9,19 etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, but with LINQ it can be achieved quite easily:

```
var numbersThatDivideByThree = numbers.Where(n=>n%3==0)
```

We use [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105, 193, 355, 653, 1201, 2209, 4063, 7473 };
            var filter = numbers.Where(i => (i % 3) == 0);

            foreach(var num in filter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(num.ToString() + ","));
            }
```

Comment: Btw. instead of the `foreach`, you could simply use `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filter));` to not have the last comma. -- if you want each number on a separate line, use `",\n"`.